# How to include multiple Java Script files using j Queryor js in asynchronous way ie. without waiting to load all js files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of javascript files and trying to load asynchronously in background. When i call function to load js it should be done in background,

I have tried below given code but i have to wait until all scripts are loaded.

```
$.getMultiScripts(jsFileArray, Server_Name+"/jspath/").done(function() {
            console.log(' all scripts loaded ');
            if(pCallBack){                               
                pCallBack();
            }
        });

    $.getMultiScripts = function(arr, path) {
        var _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr) {
            return $.getScript( (path||"") + scr );
        });

        _arr.push($.Deferred(function( deferred ){
            $( deferred.resolve );
        }));

        return $.when.apply($, _arr);
    }
```

Comment: why not use the async attribute ?

Comment: why do you need to load them via javascript and not a script tag?

Comment: So if you do not want to wait for them all then why is it coded that way?

Comment: I have load via java script because i am using object oriented java script.

Comment: @Vinayak — That isn't what object-oriented means … by any definition.